# Block .EXE in Windows Firewall with context menu

Tags: regex, windows-firewall, regedit

I got the following bit of code for a .REG file that adds "Add to Firewall" to the context menu on right clicking on a .EXE file. It simply creates an Outbound Rule in the windows firewall for that specific file you had selected instead of doing it manually.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\exefile\shell]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\exefile\shell\Add To Firewall]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\exefile\shell\Add To Firewall\command]
@="netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name=\"%1\" dir=out action=block program=\"%1\""
```

http://oi46.tinypic.com/2rgnxaf.jpg

My problem is that the following syntax `name=\"%1\"` gives the full directory (C:\New folder\test.exe) as name in the windows firewall instead of just a simple test.exe

Another feature i´m seeking is adding it all to a shift right mouse-click instead of a normal right click, cause i really don't use the feature that often so i wana see it everytime i right click on a .EXE

PS. Run the following to remove it from the context menu again.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00


[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\exefile\shell\Add To Firewall]
```

Hope to hear from someone, and in advance a big thanks from here ;)

Comment: Source link - http://maketecheasier.com/block-application-access-to-internet-from-context-menu/2011/01/11

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following will do exactly what you're asking, but it requires that you have UAC disabled. Without creating a script file or using [third](http://wintellect.com/blogs/jrobbins/elevate-a-process-at-the-command-line-in-vista) [party](http://jpassing.com/2007/12/08/launch-elevated-processes-from-the-command-line/) [tools](http://code.kliu.org/misc/elevate/), or alternatively overwriting the `runas` key, I don't think you would be able to create a UAC prompt.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\exefile\shell\firewallblock]
@="Add to Firewall"         ; String to be displayed in context menu
"HasLUAShield"=""           ; Adds UAC shield icon to the left of the command
"Extended"=""               ; Requires shift to be held when right-clicking

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\exefile\shell\firewallblock\command]
@="cmd.exe /s /c for %%a in (\"%1\") do netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name=\"%%~na\" dir=out action=block program=\"%%~nxa\""
```

To elaborate, I use the `FOR` command not because of its looping functionality but because it gives me access to [parameter extensions](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html). I modify `%%a` (which we'll say has a value of `x:\fully\qualified\path\filename.exe`) with `%%~nxa` to use `filename.exe` and `%%~na` to use `filename`.

As for the UAC stuff, I'd just use one of those third party tools I mentioned above and change the command accordingly, e.g.:

```
@="elevate.exe -c for %%a in (\"%1\") do netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name=\"%%~na\" dir=out action=block program=\"%%~nxa\""
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Sweet! works well, n all very nicely explained. Thanks ;) I normally run windows without UAC enabled, so just went with your first option.

Comment: Thank you! Minor problem I had: Your code added a rule for program.exe without path, so the program was still allowed through. I used $1 instead of %%~nxa to make it work: `@="cmd.exe /s /c for %%a in (\"%1\") do netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name=\"Block %%~na\" dir=out action=block program=\"%1\""`