# Firewall Context Menu

Tags: batch-file

### Goal

> **I need to add `Block Firewall Context Menu` For `.exe` Files.**

---

### Sources

[Block .EXE in Windows Firewall with context menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15606180/block-exe-in-windows-firewall-with-context-menu) (*Modified for my use*)

[Windows 10 | regedit | exefile shell command (firewall add rule) - not running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45896479/windows-10-regedit-exefile-shell-command-firewall-add-rule-not-running) (*No answers there*)

---

### Code

```
Reg Add "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\exefile\Shell\Firewall\Command" /T Reg_SZ /D "Elevate.exe CMD.exe /Q /C For %%%%A In (\"%%1\") Do Netsh Advfirewall Firewall Add Rule Name=\"%%~nA\" Dir=Out Action=Block Program=\"%%1\""
```

This code works perfectly fine when using it with **`filepath-that-doesnt-contain-space`**

---

If **`filepath containing spaces`** it will simply throw out this **error**. To debug, I added `& pause` to the end of the previous code

### Output

```
A specified value is not valid.

Usage: add rule name=<string>
     dir=in|out
     ..
Press any key to continue. . .
```

***Twice***

```
A specified value is not valid.

Usage: add rule name=<string>
     dir=in|out
     ..
Press any key to continue. . .
```

I am not sure why it ran the **code twice**. One theory I could come up with is that maybe it is trying add the **`folder with spaces in path as filename`** and also the **`filename`** to **`netsh`**?

---

While debugging using **`Echo`** I found out that it doesn't have **`""`** inside the **`Netsh Rule Name=""`** and **`Program=""`** which i think it requires if the **`path or filename has spaces`** in it. I believe the **`"Qoutes"`** that are missing are causing this issue probably.

I have also tried **escaping** and adding **double quotes**. Still doesn't work.

```
Reg Add "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\exefile\Shell\Firewall\Command" /T Reg_SZ /D "Elevate.exe CMD.exe /Q /C For %%%%A In (\"\"%%1\"\") Do Netsh Advfirewall Firewall Add Rule Name=\"\"%%~nA\"\" Dir=Out Action=Block Program=\"\"%%1\"\""
```

---

I hope we can figure this out together as a team. I will edit and update the OP for more clarification or updates, if needed. **Thank you to @micheal_heath for answering.**

Comment: Please do not deface your question. You can delete it yourself, or ask to disassociate yourself from your question if you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
Reg Add "HKLM\Software\Classes\exefile\shell\Firewall\command"^
 /T REG_SZ^
 /D "Elevate.exe CMD.exe /Q /C For %%%%A In (\\\"%%1\\\") Do Netsh Advfirewall Firewall Add Rule Name=\\\"%%~nA\\\" Dir=Out Action=Block Program=\\\"%%1\\\""^
 /F
```

Using [elevate](https://jpassing.com/2007/12/08/launch-elevated-processes-from-the-command-line/), you may need to escape the double quotes.
It is made from C which uses `argv` for argument handling
just like `reg` uses to parse arguments.

`reg` removes the `\` from `\"` so the `"` is kept.
The issue is that executing `elevate` with `"`, that is not
escaped with `\`, is removing the `"`.
Thus paths with spaces now have no outer `"` to keep them
from being split.

Solve this by adding another `\` preceding `\"`.
If only use one `\` to become `\\"`, escapes the following
`\` and so the `"` is removed. So add yet another `\` to become
`\\\"` to escape the `\` and to escape the `"` so that the `\`
is kept and the `"` is kept.

So `reg` parses `\\\"`, `elevate` parses `\"` and `cmd` parses `"`.

Inserted into the registry looks like:

```
Elevate.exe CMD.exe /Q /C For %%A In (\"%1\") Do Netsh Advfirewall Firewall Add Rule Name=\"%~nA\" Dir=Out Action=Block Program=\"%1\"
```